# Another word for "apply"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm in the middle of creating a web form, where users can apply for a certain service. In order to do so, they are clicking the *apply* button. Then they fill out a form and submit it. Later on, they can view their *application status*, which indicates whether the application has been processed or not.

Are there other words for *apply* and *application status* which could be used in this situation? Please note, this is not a sign up process, since not everybody meets the asked requirements.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with "apply" and "application status", personally.

Comment: Why do you want to use something else?

Comment: I'd like to find something that doesn't sound as technical as "application status" if possible.

Comment: Request, Request Status?

Comment: Eventually, I decided to use "ServiceRequest" and "ServiceRequestStatus". Everybody, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 5):

Probably not the best word choices.

For one thing, the verb *apply* has several meanings, beyond the one you intend. A naive user might well believe that your service would be "applied to them" (somehow) if they press the "apply" button. If you haven't been astonished yet at what naive users can believe, get ready.

For another thing, the noun *application* also has a number of meanings, of which one (the one that gets shortened to *app* and shows up as a file type *.app* in some systems) is central to any computing usage. The fact that that isn't what you mean probably won't help; I suggest you don't give this confusion any room to grow.

You need something that does more than merely imply a communication request instead of a piece of software. I'd go for *Submit* or *Post* for the button label, and *Status of your Submission* instead of *Application Status.*

Comment: +1 purely for *Submit*, which is a well-established usage in online forms for actually sending a communication to the organisation behind the page. As opposed to *Apply*, which often just "save changes". I just filled in my online tax return a while back. It took a while, and several times I "saved the changes made so far" - but I certainly only clicked on **Submit** once!

Comment: I am fine with *Submit*, not with *Submission Status*. The submit process concludes with submitting the application or whatever. Thereafter it is the application/whatever that has a status -- submission is past. In fact, once you click the submit button, submission status becomes 'successful', forever.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. please see my comment to the original question.

Answer (score 4):

"Apply" and "Application status" are correct in this context.

I would stick with them.